# Unit testing wpf (Disable message boxes)

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests for my code. And using 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools'.
I do not want to popup a message  while running 'Unit Test' for functions which contains message boxes. I am able to do this by using following code,

```
 public static class UnitTestDetector
{
    static UnitTestDetector()
    {
        string testAssemblyName = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework";
        UnitTestDetector.IsInUnitTest = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Any(a => a.FullName.StartsWith(testAssemblyName));
    }

    public static bool IsInUnitTest { get; private set; }
}
```

But for this solution I have to use 'IsInUnitTest' in actual function to disable message boxes. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Create interface for displaying messages

```
public interface IDisplay
{
    void ShowMessage(string message);
}
```

Pass interface to class you are testing through constructor for example

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly IDisplay _display;

    public ViewModel(IDisplay display)
    {
        _display = display;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something
        _display.ShowMessage("result of do something");
    }
}
```

Then in test you will pass implementation for the test

```
public class FakeDisplay : IDisplay
{
    public string LastDisplayedMessage => _lastDisplayedMessage;

    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        _lastDisplayedMessage = message;
    }
}

[Test]
public void WhenDoSomething_ShouldShowMessage()
{
    var fakeDisplay = new FakeDisplay();
    var viewmodel = new ViewModel(fakeDisplay);

    viewmodel.DoSomething();

    fakeDisplay.LastDisplayedMessage.Should().Be("result of do something");     
}
```

In actual production code you will implement interface which will display message and pass it to the viewmodel.

```
public class Display : IDisplay
{         
    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```